# telnet to port 8089 correct command

Tags: unix, telnet

I am using telnet to port 8089 on remote server.

Can any tell me which of the following commands are true.

```
telnet 74.255.12.25 8089
```

or

```
telnet 74.255.12.25 89
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: Did you try these commands?  What happened?

Comment: -1, the question doesn't show a personal effort from the user to look for the solution himself.

Comment: It is irrational to ask questions on Internet sites and wait, possibly forever, for a possibly incorrect answer, or possibly mutually contradictory answers among which you have to choose, when you could look up the manual and get a correct answer immediately. *man 1 telnet* would have done it. -1

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe `telnet 74.255.12.25 8089` . Why don't u try both